# Unit Test Module mocking TransportPackage

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

I'd like to unit test an Module extension I've written for Tridion 2013 SP1 in Java.

For that, I'mm thinking about sending a Mock Configuration and Processor objects (as the constructor requires it and a Mock TransportPackage to use it in

```
public void process(TransportPackage data) throws ProcessingException{}
```

Is there any recommended why of how to inject the mocked objects in there for Tridion? Since I don't see those object implementing an interface I can use to mock them.

Thanks in advance.